# How to call some value in input element in table by using Class selector and jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't call value from input in table HTML tag by using **siblings()** and **Jquery** for calculate and send result to **result selector**.

This cause might from **Siblings()** method but I don't know which one of method should be used to select value from table by using Class selector.

Here is HTML tag

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <td><strong>No</strong></td>
             <td><strong>DESCRIPTION</strong></td>
             <td><strong>Type</strong></td>
             <td><strong>QUANTITY</strong></td>
             <td><strong>UNIT PRICE</strong></td>
             <td><strong>AMOUNT (USD)</strong></td>
         </tr>
     </thead> 
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td><div><?php echo form_input('vat',set_value('',''), 'class="qty"')?> </div></td> 
 <td><div><?php echo form_input('vat',set_value('',''), 'class="unit"')?> </div></td> 
 <td><div><?php echo form_input('vat',set_value('',''), 'class="amount" readonly')?></div></td> 
                                 </tr>
 <tr> 
 <td><div><?php echo form_input('vat',set_value('',''), 'class="qty"')?></div></td> 
 <td><div><?php echo form_input('vat',set_value('',''), 'class="unit"')?> </div></td>
 <td><div><?php echo form_input('vat',set_value('',''), 'class="amount" readonly')?></div></td>
                                </tr>         
 <tr> 
 <td><div>Total</div></td>
 <td> <div><?php echo form_input('total',set_value('total',''),'class="result" readonly ')?>$</div></td>
 </tr>
```

Here is Javascript using Jquery library and I have try to select some value from input in table element by using Class selector and I will work as well for me if I don't used table.

```
$(function () {

    $('.unit,.qty').on('change', function () {
    var unit = $(this).hasClass('unit') ? $(this).val() : $(this).siblings('.unit').val();
    var qty = $(this).hasClass('qty') ? $(this).val() : $(this).siblings('.qty').val();
    unit = unit || 0;
    qty   = qty || 0;
    var val = unit >= 1 && qty >= 1 ? parseFloat(unit * qty) : 0;
    $(this).siblings('.amount').val(val);//parent()
    var total = 0;
    var update = false;
    $('.amount').each(function () {
        val = parseFloat($(this).val()) | 0;
        total = val ? (parseFloat(total + val)) : total;
    });
    $('.result').val(total);
  });
});

</script>
```

How can I do Please help>

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.qty').val()` should be `$(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('qty').val()`(same for .unit) as siblings should be inside same parent. `qty` and `unit` are not siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `closest row` like,

```
$(function () {
    $('.unit,.qty').on('change', function () {
        var $tr=$(this).closest('tr'); // usae the parent row to achieve this
        var unit = $tr.find('.unit').val();
        var qty = $tr.find('.qty').val();
        unit = unit || 0;
        qty   = qty || 0;
        var val = unit >= 1 && qty >= 1 ? parseFloat(unit * qty) : 0;
        $tr.find('.amount').val(val);//parent()
        var total = 0;
        var update = false;
        $('.amount').each(function () {
            val = parseFloat($(this).val()) | 0;
            total = val ? (parseFloat(total + val)) : total;
        });
        $('.result').val(total);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this : find the parent `tr` using `.closest()` and then find relevant `unit`,`qty` and `amount` inputs.

```
$(function () {

    $('.unit,.qty').on('change', function () {
    var $parentTR = $(this).closest('tr');

    //use parseFloat to parse value to float otherwise put it as 0
    var unit = parseFloat($parentTR.find('.unit').val()) || 0;
    var qty = parseFloat($parentTR.find('.qty').val()) || 0;

    var val = parseFloat(unit * qty);

    $parentTR.find('.amount').val(val);

    var total = 0;
    var update = false;
    $('.amount').each(function () {
        val = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
        total += val;
    });
    $('.result').val(total);
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5obcf2ef/)**